# Camera in a 2d game

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

**FOR CLARIFICATION**

I've found a video that is exactly what I'm trying to do. I marked the exact time where the youtuber talks about it, so don't skip ahead or restart the video unless you want to watch the whole thing. https://youtu.be/9V3BnBeFmLs?t=299

Goal: I have a 2d Array. Consider that I have this array in the following format:

```
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&.&&&&
&&&&&&..&&&&&.&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
```

how would I make a camera, that, based off its 2d Position (x, y) it will output:

```
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&|---|&&&.&&&&
&&&&&|..&|&&&.&&&&
&&&&&|---|&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
```

*pipes are used to represent edges of the camera output*
I've tried 2 different approaches.
#1 is I used 2 nested for loops to search each character on the 2d array within the camera's scope, starting in the upper-left hand corner. *this seems like a valid solution but it wasn't working for me*. (see [2d Array finding values from target position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307602/2d-array-finding-values-from-target-position))

#2 is hard-coding the values. for some reason nodejs didn't like this, and also it was heck to replicate, and if a array returns "`undefined`" then... the whole entire thing breaks.

For code, you can visit the link. As for strategy #2, you get the point. (just a long list of array accesses)

Notes:

- the array is structured similar to this (except much bigger):

```
[["&", "&"],
["&", "&"]]
```

Edited.
The inputs are the huge array and the camera's (x, y) position.
The output is smaller array based on the camera's (x, y) position.
Example:

```
//big array (.join(""))
         111111111
123456789012345678
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 1
&&&&&&&&&&&&&.&&&& 2
&&&&&&..&&&&&.&&&& 3
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 4
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 5
```

so the input is that array up there, and the camera's position:
lets say (14[x], 2[y]) and with a width of 1 and a height of 1 we would get the following output:

```
111
345
&&& 1
&.& 2
&.& 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The first array is the input and the 2nd array is the output? And what is the logic to create the 2nd array? Can you please supplement more?

Comment: We need to see your code, maybe an example input / desired output.

Comment: ok, working on it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```js
// This is the input. Notice how I have escaped the backslash characters in the 2nd and 6th rows.
const input = [
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','/','-','\\','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','|',':','|','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','|',':','|','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','|',':','|','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','\\','_','/','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
    ['&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&','&'],
];

/**
This function takes 4 arguments, the starting x,y for the 'zoomed' camera viewport, and w, h which define how 'tall' and 'wide' the viewport will be.

The output is a new array like the input, but constrained within the viewport options.
*/
function view(x = 11, y = 1, w = 3, h = 5) {
    const rows = [];
    for (let dy = 0; dy < h; dy += 1) {
        const row = [];
        for (let dx = 0; dx < w; dx += 1) {
            row.push(input[y + dy][x + dx]);
        }
        rows.push(row);
    }

    return rows;
}

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = view().map((row) => row.join(' ')).join('\n');
```

```css
#output {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

The output should be a 3x5 table containing the desired characters:

```
[
  [ '/', '-', '\\' ],
  [ '|', ':', '|' ],
  [ '|', ':', '|' ],
  [ '|', ':', '|' ],
  [ '\\', '_', '/' ]
]
```

Comment: Hi you can also use SO code snippet. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355

Comment: thank you for answering, sorry for confusion

Comment: @Obscuredツ Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

- Set a position where you want to put the top-left vertex of the camera

  ```
    let xVertex = 5;
    let yVertex = 1;
  ```
- Now, you should transfrom your array based in those coordenates:

  ```
    array[yVertex].splice(xVertex - 1, 5, "|", "-", "-", "-", "|");    //top edge
    array[yVertex + 1][xVertex] = "|";                                 //left edge
    array[yVertex + 1][xVertex + 4] = "|";                             //right edge
    array[yVertex + 2].splice(xVertex - 1, 5, "|", "-", "-", "-", "|");//bottom edge
  ```
- `splice()` function is very useful here. You can replace many items with just one instruction. Here more information about that https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

**EDIT**: you need to put an if statement to verify if the edges of the camera are inside the array and not outside to avoid errors.

---

- In order to get the values inside the camera, just iterate from the top-left vertex:

  ```
    let camera = [];
    for (let y = yVertex + 1; y < yVertex + 4; y++) {
        camera[y - (yVertex + 1)] = [];     //create nested array
        for (let x = xVertex + 1; x < xVertex + 4; x++) {
            camera[y - (yVertex + 1)].push(array[y][x]);   //push camera data
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: this is useful, but then how would I get the values contained inside the `|` and `-`?